# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS: cannot launch LightDM GTK+ greeter settings

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm

I am having trouble acessing the LightDM settings app on Lubuntu. I can log in to my system regularly, but i cannot tweak any of the settings, as whenever i try to launch the settings app, nothing happens. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you access it via `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings-pkexec` at terminal, do you get any clues on your terminal.  My own gives a dbind-warning, but still asks me to provide password (pkexec part) and then *LightDM GTK+ Greeter: settings* appears for me to make changes.  *Note: I wouldn't copy/paste my command, type it and use <TAB> to auto-complete or pick the correct completion.. my box runs modern Lubuntu (thus LXQt & `sddm`) so I tried on a nearby box using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and typed*

Comment: @guiverc it says that im not authorized, but im the only account on the device

Comment: Which is why the pkexec is required (ie. to activates elevated or sudo privilieges). I suggested trying from terminal, by copying & pasting that command and the resultant error message into your question I can see what you're describing and compare with a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS box (*I'm using a much later release myself*)

Comment: @guiverc this is what shows up:                   ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings ===
Authentication is required to run Settings editor for LightDM GTK+ Greeter
Authenticating as: Jp Nor,,, (telekey)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

Comment: Please don't add additional detail in comments; add to your question (using {} or code to ensure correct formatting).  Questions/Answers have better formatting & make it far easier to read; even if you can't get all the formatting correct; a lot of us can help *fine-tune* it for you  (comments can only be deleted)

Comment: The only way I can generate that error message (if I read it correctly; it's hard to view without page formatting) is by trying to execute it from a text terminal, which doesn't have access to your GUI/X to pull up the `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` app. That however is expected. You tagged Lubuntu, and you're logged into your session aren't you? (ie. LXDE/GUI)